# Is there a container for modeling publisher-subscriber relationship with fast lookup for either?

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers

I have a publisher-subscriber relationship I want to model. Publishers can have multiple subscribers, but each subscriber can only get data from a single publisher. I thought a map of vectors would be good for this:

```
std::map<publisher, std::vector<subscriber>>
```

Publisher lookup, insertion, and deletion is fast, subscriber insertion is fast, and getting all subscribers for a publisher is easy. But subscriber lookup and deletion from the map is cumbersome. It requires iterating all publishers until that subscriber is found. And I would still like an easy way of iterating through all subscribers, ideally without a double loop.

I'd like a container with these properties, where each operation is a single function call, or loop, where appropriate:

- Lookup, insertion, deletion of publishers/subscribers. O(1) or O(lg N); N = number of publishers/subscribers
- Iteration of publishers/subscribers. O(N); N = number of publishers/subscribers
- Iteration of subscriptions for a single publisher. lookup + O(N); N = number of subscribers for that publisher.

Is there a ready-made container that can do this or will I have to make a custom one?

Comment: @Enlico That has the downside that going from a publisher to the collection of subscribers is slow. I'm not sure there's a good solution that doesn't involve a pair of data structures for when you want to use multiple things as an index.

Comment: @NathanPierson, I deleted my comment exactly for that reason, to which I though too late. I think the asker should put down a bullet list of requirements, if not for anything else, just to make it easier to read.

Comment: Probably two maps could be good. One like that in the questioin, and another `std::map<std::appropriate_smart_ptr<subscriber>,std::appropriate_smart_ptr<publisher> >`. But they have to be kept syncronized... Or something. @NathanPierson, any thought?

Comment: That's my first thought as well, the difficult part is maintaining the synchronization which depends a lot on the use case. But probably just writing `subscribe(subscriber, publisher)` and `unsubscribe(subscriber, publisher)` functions and making sure each one leaves the maps in valid states would be a good first pass.

Comment: @NathanPierson, actually, if you use `shared_ptr`s in the "direct" map and `weak_ptr`s in the "reverse" map, then you can delete in the former and just check for expired `weak_ptr`s whenever you look into the latter.

Comment: What properties do `subscriber` and `publisher` have? Are they integers? If not, can they be hashed and compared for equality? Compared? Etc, etc...

Comment: @orlp They are integers, IDs of other objects.

Comment: Why do you need container for that? IMO you made this over complicated. It looks like you just need implement observer pattern and you are done.

Comment: @MarekR, I think the OP's referring to observer pattern when they write "publisher-subscriber".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
struct SubscriptionRecords {
    std::unordered_map<publisher, std::unordered_set<subscriber>>
        subscribers;
    std::unordered_map<subscriber, publisher>
        subscriptions;
};
```

Then some example methods:

```
void add_subscription(publisher p, subscriber s) {
    auto res = self->subscriptions.insert(s);
    assert(res->second);  // At most one subscription.
    self->subscribers[p].insert(s);
}

void remove_subscriber(subscriber s) {
    auto sp = self->subscriptions.find(s);
    if (sp != self->subscriptions.end()) {
        self->subscribers[*sp].erase(s);
        self->subscriptions.erase(sp);
    }
}
```

and similar.